# Unable to read from reader endpoint on AWS neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

My application as well as usage from `awscurl` fails to properly hit the `reader endpoint` of my neptune cluster. I have spawned a single read replica in addition to the primary. I try to hit the status endpoint with it and it fails (whereas the primary works)

```
awscurl https://endpoint:8182/status --service neptune-db -v
```

I use the above between primary (works) reader (doesn't work). Why would this be?

Comment: Hello - I am not able to reproduce this behavior. Where are you calling `awscurl` from? Is it possible there is a networking or security issue preventing access to the reader endpoint?

Comment: No security issues, both replicas have the same security group. I'm running locally, but I have credentials set locally as well. Primary is fine. I can post/get data with no issues. Reader endpoint fails to do anything. I've tried on both local and remote environments.

Comment: I've opened a support ticket, but I'm still replicating after 24 hours. I'm currently trying to add an additional replica to see if that changes anything, but the reader endpoint and the instance endpoint both fail.

Comment: Additional reader replica isn't making any difference, just times out when querying

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I've confirmed that reader endpoint works via bastion host, but not via my laptop. Primary endpoint works on both. Any ideas why this would be? Both inherit the same security group.

Comment: Is this via an SSH tunnel?  If yes, in order for SSL/TLS to work properly both endpoints likely need to be explicitly mapped to localhost in your hosts file.

Comment: I'm not tunneled in either. I'm just running this with local credentials loaded in. I don't have any special entries in my etc/hosts. I'm using the direct DNS name on Neptune, not localhost as well. This fails locally and on remote env over transit gateway. Primary instance works for both

Comment: This sounds like a routing issue across your transit gateway.  Have you tried using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/route-analyzer.html to see if you're actually able to route between your local machine and the reader instance?  Also, are you using NACLs at all, or just security groups in your environment?

Comment: @TaylorRiggan There was subnets inaccessible from outside internet in the subnet group, fixing that fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to summarize the discussion in the comments.

As a general rule, connection failures such as this one are caused by one or more networking or security settings. Things to check include:

1. The calling application has the appropriate role and policies in place to allow access.
2. The calling application has access to the VPC Neptune is running in.
3. The request is correctly signed in cases where IAM authentication is enabled.
4. Security groups have the required ports open
5. The Neptune service is not blocked by [Service Control Policies(SCP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html) if AWS Organizations is being used.
6. Subnets are accessible as needed.
7. Transit Gateways are working as expected. As noted in the comments the [Route Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/route-analyzer.html) can be used to help diagnose issues.